# Mocking requests in Storybook React Native

Tags: react-native, mocking, storybook, storybook-addon

I would like to be able to setup stories for my react native screens, which hooks into the API via react query hooks. I'm using the beta version of storybook react native (6.0.1-beta3).

https://storybook.js.org/addons/msw-storybook-addon, which is what I'd normally use in a react project, won't work because service workers don't exist in react native (if I'm understanding things correctly).

I have also tried installing https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-mock/, but wasn't able to get it work (storybook failed with a runtime error when trying to register the plugin... likely a version mismatch).

I might just have to go with a container/dumb component approach for the screens, but that has it's own drawbacks because queries or mutations can be nested in components.

I'm using axios for what it's worth. I've also considered putting the axios instance in a provider so I could modify the instance per test.

Thanks

Comment: msw should work since they have a react native version of the package

Comment: The version mismatch looks like an error from MSW. It simply means the worker that's running in your app is not the latest (installed) worker. Ensure `npm i msw@latest` and `npx msw init <PUBLIC_DIR>` to resolve that error.